# mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status

Tags: 14.04, email, mail, ssmtp, mailutils

I have setup mailutils and ssmtp in my Ubuntu system. I have configured `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` with proper credentials.

For testing I ran this command

```
echo "This is a test" | mail -s "Test" mygmailid
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

I do have special characters in my password.

Comment: Look into your `mail.log`

Comment: It states `Authorization failed (534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor y125sm31081621pfg.61 - gsmtp)`

Answer (score 1):

You can not use external applications with your normal password,
you must go to https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords 
and create a special password to use with your mail sender.